# How to split a this string 'gi|216ATGCTGATGCTGTG' in this format 'gi|216 ATGCTGTGCTGATGCTG' in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am parsing the fasta alignment file which contains

```
gi|216CCAACGAAATGATCGCCACACAA
gi|21-GCTGGTTCAGCGACCAAAAGTAGC
```

I want to split this string into this:

```
gi|216 CCAACGAAATGATCGCCACACAA
gi|21- GCTGGTTCAGCGACCAAAAGTAGC
```

For first string, I use

```
$aar=split("\d",$string);
```

But that didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Could you please describe your requirement? What is going wrong and how do you want the string? You have an example but no explanation! Please edit your question and update it (quick before the question closes)

Comment: Please explain your need: Is there alway a *bar*, some decimal, followed by a capital or a strike!? Would you keep everything or only one or some particular part?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!! That should be be `split(/\d/, $string)`

Answer (score 3):

So you're parsing some genetic data and each line has a `gi|` prefix followed by a sequence of numbers and hyphens followed by the nucleotide sequence? If so, you could do something like this:

```
my ($number, $nucleotides);
if($string =~ /^gi\|([\d-]+)([ACGT]+)$/) {
    $number      = $1;
    $nucleotides = $2;
}
else {
    # Broken data?
}
```

That assumes that you've already stripped off leading and trailing whitespace. If you do that, you should get `$number = '216'` and `$nucleotides = 'CCAACGAAATGATCGCCACACAA'` for the first one and `$number = '216-'` and `$nucleotides = 'GCTGGTTCAGCGACCAAAAGTAGC'` for the second one.

Looks like [BioPerl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/BioPerl/) has some stuff for dealing with fasta data so you might want to use BioPerl's tools rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd go about doing that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {

    my @strings =
        grep {m{\A \S+ \z}xms}                        # no whitespace tokens
        split /\A ( \w+ \| [\d-]+ )( [ACTG]+ ) /xms,  # capture left & right
        $line;

    print Dumper( \@strings );
}

__DATA__
gi|216CCAACGAAATGATCGCCACACAA
gi|21-GCTGGTTCAGCGACCAAAAGTAGC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a space (can't really tell from your question), use [substitution](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html). To put a space in front of any grouping of *ACTG*:

```
$string =~ s/([ACTG]+)/ \1/;
```

or to add a tab after any grouping of digits and dashes:

```
$string =~ s/([\d-]+)/\1\t/;
```

note that this will substitute on `$string` in place.

Comment: Those DNA sequences can be of arbitrary length, so your first approach tends to become increasingly ineffective because the regex has to capture a sometimes very long string. Your second approach is better because it just takes the first few characters to replace.